# Creating an ARFaceAnchor from a saved photo on iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have been following Apple's [tracking and visualizing faces](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/tracking_and_visualizing_faces) sample code in order to generate `ARFaceAnchor`s based on a given `ARSCNDelegate`:

```swift
protocol VirtualContentController: ARSCNViewDelegate {
    // The root node for the virtual content.
    var contentNode: SCNNode? { get set }
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode?
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)
}

func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {       
        guard let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor,
            let contentController = faceAnchorsAndContentControllers[faceAnchor],
            let contentNode = contentController.contentNode else { return }
        // do stuff with the faceAnchor...
}
```

(where `faceAnchorsAndContentControllers` is a simple `enum` that the example code uses to switch between different `ARFaceAnchor` effects).

I'd like to be able to create a `faceAnchor` on a saved photo. From a live camera stream, I know that still images of faces (e.g. a photo on the wall) can be detected in the same way a face with actual depth can. Is there a way to "fool" the `ARSession` into placing an `SCNNode` in an image on file within the iPhone? This would let me generate effects on saved images using the same infrastructure I have in place for live captured ones.